Blazor WASM (PWA) is not working on chrome in iPhones
It works in Chrome on all Android devices and Windows devices and also Macintosh devices, however, it didn't work in Chrome on iPhones.

Chrome on iOS is just Safari wrapped in a Chrome labeled app and Apple does not support PWAs in Safari on iOS because they fear it would hurt their profits. Safari on iOS is the new IE. It has the worst support for basic browser standards due to Apple's greed.
